# ReactJS: array in API call only displaying last element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, text, fetch-api

I'm working on a small program in ReactJS. This program calls a text file, checks it for criteria, and logs the results to an array. The array is supposed to display on the page when a button is clicked. For some reason, only the last element of the array displays -- I need the entire thing to display. Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

The idea is, I need to get an array of all the plants that contain "flower" in them and log them to the screen.

plants.txt

```
sunflower
rose
elderflower
hibiscus
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import plantsFile from 'plants.txt';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
      flower_array: undefined
    }
    getFlowers = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
        fetch(inputFile).then(data => data.text());
          let plantArray = data.split(/\r?\n/);
          let flowerArray = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < plantArray.length; i++) {
              if(plantArray.includes("flower") {
                  flowerArray.push(plantArray[i])
                  this.setState({
                    flower_array = flowerArray
                  })
            }
          }
        })
      }
render() {
    return (
      <div>
<Flower 
getFlowers = {this.getFlowers} />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

/components/Flower.js

```
import React from 'react';

class Flower extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
             <p> Flowers: {this.props.getFlowers} </p>
            </div>
            )
    }
}

export default Flower;
```

Actual output:

```
Flowers: sunflower
```

Expected output:

```
Flowers: sunflower, elderflower
```

When I do a console.log, I can clearly see that both "sunflower" and "elderflower" are being saved into the flowerArray, but only "sunflower" gets printed to the screen. Any ideas why this is happening, and how I can get multiple elements to print to the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to set state only once, instead of setting it everytime in the for loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < plantArray.length; i++) {
  if(plantArray.includes("flower") {
    flowerArray.push(plantArray[i])
  }
}
this.setState({
   flower_array
});
```

In flowers, you should use the state to pass the props.

```
<Flower getFlowers = {this.state.flower_array} />);
```

Inside Flower Component:

```
<p> Flowers: {this.props.getFlowers.join(',')} </p>
```

Also remember to set initial state to `[]` instead of undefined as `fetch` is asynchronous.

Comment: I'd rather use `filter` to find words with flowers.